# Does Salesforce1 Need Chatter To Be Enabled

Tags: chatter, salesforce1-app

I am new to Salesforce1. Having watched a few webinars, I am confused on whether it is mandatory to have Chatter enabled in order to use Salesforce1. Can someone please clarify what is the dependency of Salesforce1 with respect to Chatter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chatter should be enabled for using the Chatter feed, Groups, People and publisher actions in the Salesforce1 app. You can still use Salesforce1 to access Contacts, Accounts etc. (as well as perform CRUD operations on these objects) irrespective of whether Chatter is enabled or not. Again, integrating external apps via Canvas do not have any dependency on Chatter being enabled or disabled and would work irrespective of that.

[This](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/customize_s1_nav_about.htm) link provides information on which Salesforce1 features are dependent on Chatter being enabled.

Comment: Thanks! That link was what I was looking for. Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you need to open files or attachments in Salesforce1, you need to use Salesforce Files (a.k.a Chatter Files) with Chatter enabled.  I've found no other way to open files in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up, effective Summer '14 you won't need Chatter enabled to use actions in Salesforce1.

- If you don't have Chatter enabled at all, you won't have the Feed page in Salesforce1, but non-Chatter actions will still appear on object detail pages.
- If you have Chatter enabled, but Publisher Actions disabled, you'll get the standard Chatter actions in the web app, but all the actions will appear in Salesforce1.
- Actions will appear on object detail pages regardless of whether the object has Chatter feed tracking enabled.

See the [Summer '14 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_actions_nochatter.htm) for full details.